# Python Bokeh Random Colour Generator

Tags: python, bokeh

this is my first post here. I am writing Python code to simulate 1000 particles' random movement in 200 days and plot onto a Bokeh plot, I would like to generate a random colour code for each particle. however, seems that the plot is using the last RGB colour code to plot the points. is there a way to make the random colours to work? Thanks

```
def color_gen():
co=(round(random.random()*250),round(random.random()*250),round(random.random()*250))
return co

TOOLS="pan,wheel_zoom,reset,poly_select,box_select"


p = figure(plot_width=900, plot_height=900, 
                        x_axis_type='auto',y_axis_type='auto',
                          title='Concentration')

i=1 #Particale ID
c=1 #Days
while i<=imax:
    co=color_gen()
    # print(co)
    while c<=cmax:
        cxname="deltax"+str(c)
        xsumname="XSum"+str(c)
        p.circle(data[xsumname], c, legend_label='Partical {}'.format(c), size=2, color=co)
        c=c+1
    i=i+1

p.legend.click_policy="hide"
p.legend.location = "top_left"

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Z (m)'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'C0 (kg/cu.m)'



# show the results
show(p)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tApJw.png)

Answer (score 0):

First off, Bokeh glyphs like `circle` are intended to be used in a vectorized fashion, i.e a single call to `circle` can be used to plot 1000 circles. In fact, doing the opposite, calling `circle` 1000 times in a loop to individually plot 1000 single circles, will be ***incredibly non-performant***, both on the Python side and especially in the browser. That is simply not how the API is intended to be used.

Given your description, you should have code similar to:

```py
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'x'     : [ << 1000 x coordindates    >> ],
    'y'     : [ << 1000 y coordindates    >> ],
    'color' : [ << 1000 random RGB colors >> ],
})

plot = figure(...)
plot.circle('x', 'y', color='color', source=source)
```

That will plot 1000 circles with the 1000 random colors you put in the data source. There are other possibilities, but that is the simplest to get started with. You can read more about providing data to Bokeh in the [Providing Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html) chapter of the User's Guide.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot, I managed to add the "Color" column in my data frame, however, I failed to add that column as ColumnDataSource. not sure why
db['Color']
0        (174, 166, 100)
1        (174, 166, 100)
2        (174, 166, 100)
3        (174, 166, 100)
4        (174, 166, 100)
              ...       
26073       (81, 1, 148)
26074       (81, 1, 148)
26075    (145, 213, 189)
26076    (145, 213, 189)
26077    (246, 231, 198)
Name: Color, Length: 26078, dtype: object

Comment: I also tried to reference the db['PID'] column as the plot label, but with no luck, the legend shows the word "label" instead.
source = ColumnDataSource(data={
    'x'     : db['SumX'],
    'y'     : db['SumY'],
    'color' : db['Color'],   
    'label' : db['PID']
})

Comment: try using RGB hex color strings as the values in the data source